# Heroku: Bundler intermittently fails with OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError: SSL_read:: decryption failed or bad record mac

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, openssl, bundler

My rails app, for some unknown reason, will fail to push to Heroku 29/30 times. It will fail on different gems, but always with the same error: `OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError: SSL_read:: decryption failed or bad record mac`. Does anyone have any ideas?

I've read about this error in other contexts, but at the point of the bundler I feel like there is very little I can do about it…

Logs for heroku push:

```
Counting objects: 35, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (21/21), done.
Writing objects: 100% (21/21), 2.55 KiB, done.
Total 21 (delta 19), reused 0 (delta 0)

-----> Removing .DS_Store files
-----> Fetching custom git buildpack... done
-----> Ruby app detected
-----> Compiling Ruby/Rails
-----> Using Ruby version: ruby-1.9.3
-----> Installing dependencies using Bundler version 1.3.2
   Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs vendor/bundle/bin --deployment
   Fetching source index from https://rubygems.org/
   Using i18n (0.6.1)
   Using builder (3.0.4)
   Using multi_json (1.8.2)
   Using journey (1.0.4)
   Using hike (1.2.3)
   Using tilt (1.4.1)
   Using rake (10.1.0)
   ... <<truncated for brevity>>
   Using chunky_png (1.2.9)
   Using httpauth (0.2.0)
   Using kgio (2.8.1)
   Using memcachier (0.0.2)
   Using http_parser.rb (0.5.3)

   OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError: SSL_read:: decryption failed or bad record mac
   Using libxml-ruby (2.7.0)
   Using newrelic_rpm (3.6.8.168)
   Using libv8 (3.11.8.17)
   An error occurred while installing modernizr-rails (2.6.3), and Bundler cannot
   continue.
   Make sure that `gem install modernizr-rails -v '2.6.3'` succeeds before
   bundling.
 !
 !     Failed to install gems via Bundler.
 !

 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app
```

Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '1.9.3'
gem 'rails', '3.2.13'

gem 'pg'
gem 'koala'

gem 'unicorn', '~> 4.6.3'
gem 'asset_sync'

gem 'json'
gem 'omniauth-facebook'
gem 'twitter', :git => 'git://github.com/sferik/twitter.git', :tag => 'v5.0.0.rc.1'
gem 'twitter-text'
gem 'typus'
gem 'certified'
gem 'taps'
gem 'kaminari'
gem 'rack'
gem 'mobile-fu'
gem 'newrelic_rpm', '~> 3.6.8.168'
# gem 'td'
gem 'libxml-ruby'

# gem 'rails_12factor', group: :production
gem 'mandrill-api'
# gem 'cocoon'
gem 'delayed_job_active_record'
# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.

group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'
  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
  gem 'jquery-rails'
  gem 'jquery-ui-rails'
  gem 'noty-rails'
  gem 'add-to-homescreen-rails'
  gem 'less-rails'
  gem 'therubyracer'
  gem 'libv8', '~> 3.11.8'
  gem 'modernizr-rails'
  gem 'compass-rails'
  gem 'zurb-foundation'
  gem 'foundation-icons-sass-rails'
  gem 'momentjs-rails'
  gem 'bourbon'
  gem 'jquery-mobile-rails'
  gem 'dalli'
  gem 'memcachier'
end

group :test do
  gem 'sqlite3'
  gem 'simplecov'
end
```